# My BeautifulSoup spider only crawls 2 pages not all the pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Any help would be appreciated as I am new to python. I have created the below Web Crawler but it doesn't crawl all the pages, just 2 pages. What changes need to be made for it to crawl all the pages?

See def trade_spider(max_pages) loop and at the bottom i have trade_spider(18) which should loop all pages.

Thanks for your help.

```
import csv
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('dataoutput.csv','w', newline= "")
writer = csv.writer(f)

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/nottingham/?price_max=200000&identifier=nottingham&q=Nottingham&search_source=home&radius=0&pn=' + str(page) + '&page_size=100'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'listing-results-price text-price'}):
            href = "http://www.zoopla.co.uk" + link.get('href')
            title = link.string 
            get_single_item_data(href) 
        page += 1
def get_single_item_data(item_url): 
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

    for item_name in soup.findAll('h2', {'itemprop': 'streetAddress'}):
     address = item_name.get_text(strip=True)
writer.writerow([address])
trade_spider(18)
```

Comment: Is there an error that occurs or does it exit cleanly? Does the `page` variable make it to 18 or just 2?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, it does crawl all the pages (though there are just 14 pages not 18). It seems like your trying to scrape street address , in that case the second function is unnecessary and is only making your crawler slow by calling requests.get() too many times. I've modified the code a little but this one is faster.

```
import csv
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('dataoutput.csv','w', newline="")
writer = csv.writer(f)

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        furl = 'http://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/nottingham/?price_max=200000&identifier=nottingham&q=Nottingham&search_source=home&radius=0&pn=' + str(page) + '&page_size=100'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

        # Changed the class' value

        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'listing-results-address'}):     
            #href = "http://www.zoopla.co.uk" + link.get('href')
            #title = link.string 
            #get_single_item_data(href)
            address = link.get_text()
            print (address)               # Just to check it is working fine.
            writer.writerow([address])

        print (page)
        page += 1

# Unnecessary code

'''def get_single_item_data(item_url): 
source_code = requests.get(item_url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

for item_name in soup.findAll('h2', {'itemprop': 'streetAddress'}):
    address = item_name.get_text(strip=True)
    writer.writerow([address])'''

trade_spider(18)
```

Comment: Thanks Rajeev, looks like the above code will get the address but I want more information than the address which needs it to go into each link and get that information. Even putting trade_spider(14) still only returns 2 pages of results, any ideas?

Comment: I reran your code and it returned information from all the pages. Maybe some other part of code(that you may have not posted) is causing problem

Comment: Thanks Rajeev, there is a non type error occuring. How do I get past none types?

Comment: I cannot help you on that without seeing the code. Upload your code somewhere and share its link , if you do not have any problem with that.